# Path param gets null instead of value

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I hava simple rest method looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changePlan/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void changePlan(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    new Planner().changePlan(id);
}
```

Does anyone know why **id** in my case is null? When I've checked path from HttpServletRequest there actually is path changePlan/123456 but String **id** is still null

Comment: Note to eligible voters: Would appreciate votes to [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-mvc/synonyms) `spring-web` to `spring-mvc`.

Comment: Does it really deserve so many minuses?

Comment: Dunno. I didn't vote either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@PathParam` isn't a Spring annotation. Use `@PathVariable`.

Answer (score 2):

[`@PathParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) belongs to JAX-RS while you are working with Spring MVC and so you need [`@PathVariable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation to catch the value.